# Child route template not rendered when parent overrides renderTemplate

Tags: ember.js, routes

My routes are:

```
this.resource('workpaper', function() {
    this.route('add');
});
```

For the `workpaper` route I would like to decide which template is rendered, so in the `WorkpaperRoute` I override `renderTemplate()`:

```
renderTemplate: function(controller, model) {
    this.render('workpaper/index');
}
```

The problem is that when I navigate to the `add` route, the `workpaper/index` template is rendered, instead of the `workpaper/add` template.

Overiding `renderTemplate()` in `WorkpaperAddRoute` seemed to have no effect:

```
renderTemplate: function(controller, model) {
    this.render('workpaper/add');
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you visit a route like `workpaper.add` Ember will load the `WorkpaperAddRoute` but it will also load the `WorkpaperRoute` and `ApplicationRoute` above it. This means you can still access things like models from parent routes. Overriding `renderTemplate` on the `WorkpaperRoute` will affect all of that route's children.

To achieve what you're aiming for, try overriding `renderTemplate` on the `WorkpaperIndexRoute` instead.